# Way to find variable=value using sed & awk in bash

Tags: bash, ksh

How to extract `variable=value` in a string using `sed` & `awk`?

e.g. consider following string,

> Hi Folks how are you. I want to extract `birthdate=July0808128` from this string.

Comment: You want to extract "birthdate" and "July0808128"?....what have you tried?

Comment: I used long creepy grep -wd expression

Comment: `ksh`, or `bash`? They're two different shells (actually, there are a **lot** of different, and mutually incompatible, shells being distributed under the ksh name; I'm in the camp where if it isn't written by David Korn, it's not real ksh. The clones, like pdksh or mksh, are usually missing features). If it's bash, you have `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`, so you don't need `sed` *or* `awk`.

Comment: BTW -- note that half the tooltip for the downvote button is *"does not show any research effort"*. It helps -- a lot -- to show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ s="birthdate=July0808128"

$ echo "${s%=*}"
birthdate

$ echo "${s#*=}"
July0808128
```

--edit--

> I have file which many lines. out of which 3 lines are like, >Hi Rock
>   how are you. I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 from this string. >Hi Akshay how are you. I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 from this string. I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 out of above
>   string

```
grep -Po 'birthdate=\w+' yourfile
```

OR

```
grep -Po 'birthdate=\w+[0-9]{7}' yourfile
```

Should work.

Comment: I want to extract whole string not just a value,
birthdate=July0808128

Comment: I have file which many lines. out of which 3 lines are like,

>Hi Rock how are you. I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 from this string.

>Hi Akshay how are you. I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 from this string.

I want to extract birthdate=July0808128 out of above string.

Comment: Thanks. Can we do this using sed or awk?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` to split at the `=`

```
variable=$(awk -F'=' '{print $1}')
value=$(awk -F'=' '{print $2}')
echo $variable $value
```

One way to do this in a one liner is to use the `read` function to read the output of `awk` or whatever command you use.  For example:

```
line="birthdate=July0808128"
read variable value <<< $(echo $line | awk -F'=' '{print $1 " " $2}')
echo $variable
echo $value
```

will output

```
birthdate
July0808128
```

Comment: can we do this in one liner like, find a word & extract word=value?

Comment: @Rock actually stumbled across an answer to your one liner question while working something else yesterday.